# CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE_CXX doesn't find the header

Tags: c++, cmake, pugixml, orthanc-server

I am trying to compile a project in C++ coded by other persons (Orthanc for the people that knows a bit of medical imaging) on Ubuntu 22.04.
One library needed is pugixml but CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE_CXX doesn't seem to find the header of that library

I have installed pugixml through apt-get and I also have downloaded the library and put it in /usr/lib/.

I also checked the source code and this is the function call that returns the error

```
CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE_CXX(pugixml.hpp HAVE_PUGIXML_H)
  if (NOT HAVE_PUGIXML_H)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Please install the libpugixml-dev package")
  endif()

  link_libraries(pugixml)
```

and when we include that library with no set up (I'll put all the inclusions)

```
include(CMakePushCheckState)
include(CheckFunctionExists)
include(CheckIncludeFile)
include(CheckIncludeFileCXX)
include(CheckIncludeFiles)
include(CheckLibraryExists)
include(CheckStructHasMember)
include(CheckSymbolExists)
include(CheckTypeSize)
include(FindPythonInterp)
```

this is the command I use for the cmake (given by the documentation of orthanc) :

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DUSE_SYSTEM_CIVETWEB=OFF -DALLOW_DOWNLOADS=ON path/to/Orthanc/orthanc/OrthancServer
```

Does someone know what I can do to resolve that problem?
Rewriting the code isn't a possibility for me thus I'd prefer to use Pugixml.

EDIT : This is the complete logs that appear when I launch `cmake --fresh`

```
CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:21 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 3.5 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.4.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Warning (dev) at /home/ypollet/Numerisation/Orthanc/orthanc/OrthancFramework/Resources/CMake/OrthancFrameworkConfiguration.cmake:46 (include):
  Policy CMP0148 is not set: The FindPythonInterp and FindPythonLibs modules
  are removed.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0148" for policy details.  Use
  the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:79 (include)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3.10 (found version "3.10.12") 
-- Looking for sqlite3.h
-- Looking for sqlite3.h - found
SQLite include dir: /usr/include
Detected version of SQLite: 3037002
-- Found OpenSSL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so (found version "3.0.2")  
-- Found CURL: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so (found version "7.81.0")  
-- Looking for C++ include civetweb.h
-- Looking for C++ include civetweb.h - not found
CMake Error at /home/ypollet/Numerisation/Orthanc/orthanc/OrthancFramework/Resources/CMake/CivetwebConfiguration.cmake:108 (message):
  Please install the libcivetweb-dev package
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /home/ypollet/Numerisation/Orthanc/orthanc/OrthancFramework/Resources/CMake/OrthancFrameworkConfiguration.cmake:306 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:79 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

The warning is because the project ask for a cmake version of atleast 2.8 with CMP0058 :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
cmake_policy(SET CMP0058 NEW)
```

my version is :

```
$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.27.0

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

Comment: Header files are usually in `/usr/include`. That's where the `apt` command should have added it. Did you install the *development* package? Is the header file in a *subdirectory*? Is it really `/usr/include/pugixml.h` or more like `/usr/include/pugixml/pugixml.h` (or similar)?

Comment: Also if you download and install manually (for example by building from source and installing) You should never put those files directly in `/usr`. If there's an `install` target you should use it, it should install it in the proper location, which is likely somewhere under `/usr/local`. You might have to add `/usr/local/include` to the header file paths to be searched, as well as `/usr/local/lib` for the linker libraries.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The file is in `/usr/include/pugixml.hpp`,  as well as `pugiconfig.hpp` (I don't know if this one is relevant)

Comment: @Broot: As the output of `cmake --fresh` tells you, please install the `libcivetweb-dev` package :).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I guess should have used `cmake --fresh` when I added the package because of the Cache

Comment: @Broot: On Stack Overflow we do not mix problems and solutions in a single post. A question post is intended for state the problem only. All solutions should be posted as answer(s). If you, as a question's author, know the solution, then you could write an answer by yourself: https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE_CXX`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckIncludeFileCXX.html) will check the same include directories as the selected compiler would to confirm whether an include file is present.

On the [Ubuntu Package Search](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=pugixml&searchon=names&suite=jammy&section=all) we can see that the file [`/usr/include/pugixml.hpp`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/amd64/libpugixml-dev/filelist) is part of the [libpugixml-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/libpugixml-dev) package. If `CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE_CXX` does not find that file, despite `/usr/include` being part of the default compiler include paths on Ubuntu, I conclude that you do not have that package installed. Did you maybe just install the `libpugixml1v5` package and forgot the dev one?
After you installed it, please don't forget to run `cmake --fresh <src_directory>` in your build directory, to reset the build cache.

For a minimum reproducable example, you could place the following in a `CMakeLists.txt` in an empty folder and type `cmake .` into your console (in that folder), to see if you get an error:

```
project(test)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
include(CheckIncludeFileCXX)
CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE_CXX(pugixml.hpp HAVE_PUGIXML_H)
if(HAVE_PUGIXML_H)
    message(STATUS "pugixml.hpp found")
else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "pugixml.hpp not found")
endif()
```

Comment: The first lib that I installed is the dev one (because it was the one cited in the error message). I don't know if it's an error, but I added libpugixml1v5 as well (after a few failed attempts). And /usr/include/pugixml.hpp exists

Comment: Oops sorry, forgot that part.
That's so weird, it found the library : `pugixml.hpp found`.
That means that the error comes from the project I guess. (It's huge, there is so many cmake files that calls each other, and I'm not used to C++)

Comment: @Broot: So the specific problem that this question asked about is resolved? Please be so kind to accept / upvote this answer then :).

Comment: nope because the error still appears on the project

Comment: @Broot: Let's continue this in chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255894/check-include-file-cxx-doesnt-find-the-header

Comment: Unfortunately, I lack reputation to enter be able to enter the group chat. I will edit my post on the matter

Comment: @Broot: ah that sucks. sorry for the confusion, I wasn't aware of that stupid restriction.

Comment: @Broot: You should be able to use chat now: [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255895/discussion-between-chrisb-and-broot).

Answer (score 0):

The final answer was to use `cmake --fresh` to clear the cache.